# Getting process start time as future date in sigar java api

Tags: java, solaris, sigar

As i am using sigar java api to get the process start time in solaris sparc OS,
Currently am getting a future start time as return.

Could anyone suggest what can be the issue?

```java
try {
    startTime = sigar.getProcTime(pid).getStartTime();
} catch (SigarException e) {
}
```

Output: 20230720151134 (converted july 20 2023)

When we tried with

```bash
perl -e'@d=localtime ((stat(shift)) [9]) ; printf"%4d%02d%02d----" /proc/34411
```

I am getting correct output.

Comment: Cite example output.

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: Link to documentation for `getProcTime`.

Comment: Using Java 1.8 version

Comment: What does `ps -f -p PID` show for the `STIME` value - that's the start time.  Your Perl code is getting the time from the timestamp of the `/proc/PID` directory entry.  Sigar is probably getting it from `/proc/PID/status`, while `ps` will get the start time from `/proc/PID/psinfo`.  Depending on what version of Solaris your Sigar install was built for, the location of the start time data in the file could have moved.

Comment: There is hardly any documentation we could find, only option is to dig into api . But in core api's native codes are there and difficult find the root cause.

Comment: I didn't understand the line "the location of the start time data in the file could have moved" Why its strange for solaris? Any way to fix this behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

The authors of SIGAR chose to calculate start time [using this calculation](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/blob/ad47dc3b494e9293d1f087aebb099bdba832de5e/src/os/solaris/solaris_sigar.c#L768-L769):

```c
proctime->start_time = usage.pr_create.tv_sec + sigar->boot_time;
proctime->start_time *= MILLISEC;
```

This assumes that both the process create time and boot time are accurate.  Since you are getting times in the future, this is obviously not the case.

To debug which of those two elements is wrong, you'd need to run code that populates that structure, which reads the contents of `/proc/pid/usage` into it; it obtains `boot_time` from KSTAT.

I just queried these values on the GNU Compile Farm Solaris SPARC box (gcc211): The actual process start time from `psinfo` (and confirmed by matching actual Unix time) was 1685507726287.

I got a boot time of 1652966303 (from `kstat -p unix:0:system_misc:boot_time`) and create time from `usage` of 32551759.  Adding those times together gives 1685518062000 which is 10335713 milliseconds (2.87 hours) ahead of the actual start time.  Further investigation shows the boot time (compared to days+hours+minutes of up time) to be the primary source of that 10336-second difference.

Poking around the internet it appears that boot time [is inaccurate in a zone](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/37318) and potentially doesn't reset on a reboot, and other various issues (enter "Solaris boot time inaccurate" in your favorite search engine), so the SIGAR code does appear to be a bug (at least in versions after 8).

I'm not sure why the authors of SIGAR didn't just use the start time from `psinfo` for this data, and their approach may have worked when they wrote it for an earlier Solaris version.  However, the last release was 12 years ago and the last commit to the SIGAR repository was 7 years ago.  Any bug won't be fixed.  There are alternative actively-maintained Java-based projects to give you information like this, one of which I maintain.